# Pros and cons of semantically-significant capitalization

Tags: semantics, identifiers

In Go, [capitalized identifiers are public (exported)](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers), while lowercase identifiers are private (within the package it's defined in). Most other programming languages don't have this sort of semantic difference of public/private by capitalization.

Cognate [ignores non-capitalized tokens](https://github.com/cognate-lang/cognate#cognate-is-readable) to allow for more natural language-looking code. Most programming languages don't have this due to their case-sensitivity for identifiers.

**What are the pros and cons of semantically significant capitalization?**

Comment: CON: NOT ALL COMPUTERS CAN GENERATE LOWERCASE LETTERS, WELL, NOT A PROBLEM WITH CURRENT COMPUTERS, BUT IN THE PAST THIS WAS THE CASE.

Comment: @GlenYates Aʜ, ꜰᴀɪʀ ᴘᴏɪɴᴛ. Bᴜᴛ ꜱᴜʀᴇʟʏ ᴛʜᴇʏ ᴄᴏᴜʟᴅ ꜱᴛɪʟʟ ᴅᴏ ꜱᴍᴀʟʟ ᴄᴀᴘꜱ?

Comment: Historically, I believe the significance of a leading capital was introduced by Smalltalk in the early 70s. As @GlenYates has so strikingly reminded us, this was roughly at the point where the industry started moving from 6-bit single-case character sets to ASCII and EBCDIC.

Comment: One drawback is that when case is semantically significant in natural language, as occasionally it is in German and English, being forced to use a particular case for the sake of the programming language can be awkward.

Comment: @GlenYates Ummm... what?

Comment: @user16217248-OnStrike: Some older computer systems have character sets that lack case! The DEC PDP-10 is a notable example—the system used a form of case-folded ASCII called SIXBIT for symbols and filenames, so you could pack a six-character name into a single 36-bit word. Some video terminals’ bitmap character sets lacked graphics for lowercase letters, too. So cased languages like Prolog had provisions for this: in DECsystem-10 Prolog you could set a flag with `:-'NOLC'.` to let you write a statement like `p(X, Y):-q(Y).` as `P(_X, _Y):-Q(_Y).` instead.

Answer (score 39):

### Con: Doesn't work well for identifiers in alphabets other than latin

Most programing langues nowadays support unicode identifiers. This allows writing identifiers in languages other than english. However, capitalization does not exist in every language and may have other roles than in English.

Is מזהה public or private? You can't really tell. People writing code in such languages will be forced to prefix their identifiers with latin letters to get the desired behavior. Not an ideal situation.

Even in languages that have the concept of capitalization it may not be trivial to substitute a lower case word with one that starts with a upper case. For example in Greek different cases of constants have different meanings.

Comment: Technically, case sensitivity *would* work for Greek/Coptic, Cyrillic, Armenian, and a few other scripts.  But yeah, you can't really capitalize a Hebrew letter or Chinese ideograph.

Comment: (for the curious, מזהה means "id")

Comment: I'm never convinced there's a significant portion of programs written in non-English languages. Do you have stats?

Comment: @PasserBy try searching for a relatively obscure problem, and many times after the first couple of pages of google results you usually start seeing chinese coding Q&A sites

Comment: @Pyritie But do they _code_ in Chinese? Or are you saying the discussion is in Chinese, which of course there'd be plenty.

Comment: @PasserBy Yes, you will find variable and function names are often a mix between English scripts and other scripts

Comment: @PasserBy I’ve seen quite a bit of code old code using Cyrillic (remember, the USSR was isolated technologically during the early years of electronic computers), and a nontrivial amount of modern code that uses CJK unified ideographs mixed with Latin characters (this is rather common for isolated projects coming out of China). And then there’s always the cases of ALGOL 68, Citrine, Internaitional Scheme, Scratch, or FOCAL (all localized to varying degrees to numerous languages).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn The part where code coming from China often contains Chinese characters is a lot more significant. I don't think anyone designing a new language should bother about what happened with the USSR.

Comment: Well, you could take the C approach and just disallow Unicode identifiers.

Comment: “For example in Greek different cases of constants have different meanings” — What does this mean, exactly? What is the difference in meaning between _αναγνωριστικό_ and _Αναγνωριστικό_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you are writing Greek as someone from greece there is no difference but in mathematics you use the same symbols and the meaning is completely different

Comment: The case distinction applies to single Greek letters.  For example, in statistics, `Σ` is a sum, while `σ` is a standard deviation.

Comment: Usually yes, you might hypothetically have a variable named something like `ζ_squared`. However, even if you use just single letter variables treating them differently seems ill advised

Comment: @PasserBy: The reason there aren't many is at least partly that languages have had very poor support for non-latin source text...

Comment: @user16217248-OnStrike: C does not "disallow Unicode identifiers".

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE In C, you cannot have any characters other than `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_` in identifiers.

Comment: @user16217248-OnStrike: 6.4.2.1 ¶1 specifically defines the syntax for identifier swith `universal-character-name` as one of the cases for `identifier-nondigit`. While only the `\u` encoding is **required** to be supported by any implementation, ¶3 allows that literal multibyte sequences may also be accepted and interpreted as corresponding to Unicode characters if the implementation chooses to do so.

Comment: So, far from "disallowing Unicode identifiers", it mandates support for them in at least one form, and gives implementations the freedom (which all modern ones take) to accept them in the preferred form (literal UTF-8 text).

Comment: @user16217248-OnStrike https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6Fhsz80oUrs-7Pu36lOtTFGwNjawh4je1QBK5iZl5GpoK1VwKQFBQBBRK01BSTVHSgWvRtOaqheiAmQgA

Answer (score 27):

### Con: inflexibility

Using Go as an example, if you have a private identifier and want to make it public, you have to effectively rename it, which means changing code at every point where the identifier is used, as opposed to just changing the declaration. And since there are only two letter cases, it prevents the language from adding another option, such as some kind of partially exported identifiers.

As another example, if a language uses capitalization to distinguish between types and variables, it's going to cause problems if you later want to add the ability to use types as values (“first-class types”):

Comment: In my personal experience (we use a prefix for non-public members in C# which we're supposed to remove if we make it public), your first point is rarely a problem: Since a public method is part of the API, it has different requirements (regarding parameter validation etc.) than a private method. So, often, you need to change other aspects of the method as well when making it public or just "wrap" it with a new public method. If the method can really be made public as it is, the IDE makes renaming it everywhere easy, since it had limited scope so far.

Comment: Javascript's `#private` fields are another example where you have to rename things to change their visibility.

Answer (score 18):

Cons:

You move representation of a binary property into the identifier concept. Go is actually a good example of why this is a bad idea. With their decision, they are now stuck with a binary visibility concept. Most language have either nothing ore a lot more granularity than that. The Go way, you can't share definitions between an API and an implementation package.

For most languages, there is syntax highlighting which allows you to colorize the visibility definition and ignore it, if you don't care.

The highlevel point against is that such decisions are usually made at a stage where the language is still very simple and the decision looks reasonable. However, languages get more complex if they are successful. But such fundamental decisions cannot be undone in a compatible way. Adding another keyword or braces where they weren't allowed before is a mostly or completely compatible change.

Comment: What do you mean by _"you can't share definitions between an API and an implementation package"_? What isn't shared? Why do you have two packages? What hypothetically solves your problem?

Comment: If a struct in your API has a field, that field is either public or your implementation is in the API package. Having API and implementation in the same package is uncommon in all languages and doesn't play well with code generators often used in Go. A solution is to restrict visibility to a group of packages like private[package] in Scala. Java modules also provide a solution that is more complex as they had to add it at a later point.

Comment: I have no experience in Go code generators, but having the API and implementation in the same package is pretty much intended isn't it?

Comment: "For most languages, there is syntax highlighting which allows you to colorize the visibility definition and ignore it, if you don't care." I have seen color highlights, but never what you are describing. What language and editor combo has this?

Comment: @James most languages use ordinary keywords for this purpose and all IDEs I've seen in the last two decades had special colors for at least the entire keyword group. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think I was misreading "ignore it" as the IDE hiding the accessibility modifier words from you.

Answer (score 13):

Case has long been used by convention to indicate roles of identifiers. For instance, in C it's conventional to use ALLUPPER for macros, and either snake_case or camelCase for other identifiers. In many languages, classes are conventionally named with an initial uppercase letter; this usually goes along with camelCase for the rest of the name.

Making this semantically significant simply formalizes these common programming styles. It's analogous to the way languages like Python make indentation significant to the parser, rather than it just being used to make the code easier for humans to read.

So the main "pro" is that programs in the language are forced to follow a consistent style, making it easier for everyone to read each other's programs.

This can also make it easier for programming tools to provide assistance.

The con, as other answers say, is that it doesn't work well when programming in (human) languages that don't have upper/lowercase similar to Latin alphabets.

Comment: In C, macros are not always capitalized. For instance `bool` is a macro expanding to `_Bool`, dating back to C99.  There is often a `getc` macro in `<stdio.h>` implementations.  Lower cased macros are used for shortening nested member access in structures: `#define s6_addr in6_u.u6_addr8`. It would be bad for macros to be restricted to upper case or even a leading upper case character.

Comment: @Kaz `getc()` is specified as a function, but built-in functions are allowed to be implemented as macros. I think `bool` is an exception because it was originally an implementation extension keyword, and when it became a standard macro they kept the lowercase name for compatibility.

Comment: In ISO C there are other examples of lower case macros. The `errno` symbol from `<errno.h>` is explicitly defined a macro in ISO C which "expands to a modifiable lvalue".  The behavior is undefined if a program uses `#undef` on it to access an `errno` object.   In `<stdio.h>`, `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are also defined as macros. (And have were that way in ancient Unix; something along the lines of `#define stdin __filetab[0]` or whatever.)  In `<assert.h>`, `assert` is a macro.

Comment: @Kaz The common denominator is that these things are used as if they're variables or functions, but they've been implemented as macros for various reasons (e.g. `errno` because of multi-threading).

Answer (score 7):

One advantage is that you can lexically distinguish between two different classes of identifier, which could be useful if they need to be parsed differently.

A good example of this is Haskell, which uses capitalized identifiers to denote types, and non-capitalized for functions.  This avoids the need for its parser to determine based on the context which kind of identifier it is looking at, and results in a simpler, more efficient parser.

Comment: I think your remark about Haskell is wrong. In value contexts, it uses lowercase for variables and uppercase for constructors; in type contexts, it uses lowercase for type variables and uppercase for types.

Comment: @xigoi - probably; it's been a while since I last used Haskell, so could easily have misremembered the details.  I think my point still remains valid, though.

Answer (score 6):

Con: screenreaders typically either don’t announce all-caps any differently to lowercase words, or, worse, can read them letter by letter as if they were an abbreviation.

Language developers shouldn’t bake in inaccessible practices into the base system.

Comment: This is an issue with screen readers (which are generally not designed to read code), not the with code itself.

Comment: Well, that boils down to a philosophical code-is-for-computers can code-is-for-users. Personally I always go for the second option.

Comment: I somehow agree, but does _any_ screen reader read the code correctly (as e.g. "tab string my string equals quote foo quote semicolon new line")?

Comment: Anyone using a screen reader for working with code in detail is likely to need to find one that is able to distinguish between cases anyway, as most languages are case significant.   Most visually-impaired programmers I've talked to use a program called NVDA, which [seems to support this](https://nvda.groups.io/g/nvda/topic/nvda_announcing_capital/88508837?p=)

Answer (score 5):

Similar to occipita's answer, but for humans instead of compilers:

When reading code, it can be useful to immediately be able to tell whether a given identifier is public or private, without going to find its definition (using the example of Go). This will make it easier to pick out identifiers that definitely came from the current file, and which might have come from elsewhere. It might also allow you to make quicker and better decisions on whether you can safely change a function: if it's capitalised, then it's likely to be used somewhere else in the codebase, so changing it might be riskier.

Comment: Because the behavior of private functions is never exposed through the public API? This is complete nonsense. It does not matter if a bug is introduced from code that can be called directly or not.

Comment: @feldentm Ok maybe not the behaviour necessarily, but the type signature for example. Surely you can see what I mean even if the example isn't totally applicable

Answer (score 5):

## Cons: not extensible

There are only two cases. It can be a hard time if, for example, we need to add `protected` support to a newer version of the language.

## Cons: dynamic keys

For example, in JavaScript, objects are often used as maps, and class properties can be dynamic too. A static analyser cannot tell if `obj.x` is accessing a private property, or reading the value corresponding to a user input `x`.

## Cons: special words

Some words are written in specific cases. For example, forcing `iOS` to be `ios` or `IOS` at language level can be a bit ugly.